# Legitimate uses of ReferenceEquals()

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, collections, reference

In a .NET program that's written to follow declarative style, what are some legitimate uses for ReferenceEquals()?

Comment: A legitimate use is when you want to answer the question "do these two references refer to the same object"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with declarative style, and how does that relate to referential equality?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code where you find ReferenceEquals to be used unreasonably?  If so, we may be able to suggest some arguments in favor of your position.

Comment: I would strongly argue that if you are comparing threads for equality (by ID *or* reference equality) you are almost certainly doing something wrong.  There is almost no reason to do that.  The one common case is invoking to the UI thread, and there are better (built-in) ways to do that.

Comment: I would write `if (Thread.CurrentThread != RequestHandlerThread)`, but using `ReferenceEquals` is less ambiguous, because you don't have to worry whether the type has overridden the `==` and `!=` operators.  I don't feel strongly about comparing the thread object vs its ID, but I would lean towards comparing the object.  In addition to the object orientation argument, it also requires fewer indirections.

Comment: @phoog Thread is a sealed class, and it does not override said operators

Comment: @GregC *I* know that, and *you* obviously know that, but does *every programmer reading the code* know that, without having to go look it up?

Comment: I reverted back to my original question, and continued the Thread-specific discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/q/9912593/90475

Comment: For classes which are not expected to override `Equals`, the non-virtual `ReferenceEquals` method is faster than using `Equals` with its associated virtual dispatch.  The speed advantage is sufficient to justify using it in place of `Object.Equals(Object,Object)`.  A more interesting question is whether doing anything special when `Equals(X,Y)` is true but `ReferenceEquals(X,Y)` is false should be considered a violation of encapsulation.  IMHO, in a very real sense it should.

Comment: @supercat This sounds like an answer.  In some rare cases where performance is of utmost importance.  It's common to see really ugly code in places that require utmost performance.  The place that adversary is trying to develop has code that doesn't run slow, but is fairly, well, ugly code.

Comment: @GregC: Having the `==` operator in C# call `Object.Equals` rather than performing a reference comparison equivalent to `ReferenceEquals` would make a lot of code run a lot slower.  Conceptually, given `string s1="0"; string s2=0.ToString(); string s3=s1;"` it should not be possible to tell whether `s3` was copied from `s2` or `s1`, but ensuring that all strings containing the same characters really were indistinguishable would be costly and not really offer much benefit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "written to follow declarative style", but `ReferenceEquals` is usually used when overriding the `==` operator.  From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx:

```
public static bool operator ==(ThreeDPoint a, ThreeDPoint b)
{
    // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
    if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // If one is null, but not both, return false.
    if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if the fields match:
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y && a.z == b.z;
}
```

It is important to see the **Note** below for the justification:

> **Note:** A common error in overloads of operator == is to use (a == b), (a == null), or (b == null) to check for reference equality. This
>   instead creates a call to the overloaded operator ==, causing an
>   infinite loop. Use ReferenceEquals or cast the type to Object, to
>   avoid the loop.

Comment: @GregC The check is necessary here, else the `null==null` scenario will break. Also note that the `null` checks themselves use referential equality. They just use cast-to-object instead of `ReferenceEquals`. (`ReferenceEquals(a,b)` is equivalent to `(object)a==(object)b`)

Comment: @GregC It's not guaranteed to be the same, but from the context it appears that it ought to be the same.  If it would act differently it would most likely be because of a bug in the deep equality portion.

Comment: If the check for ReferenceEquals wasn't there and both a and b were null, this would return false.  As it is, it returns true.

Comment: It would probably make sense to make the null check there an XOR.  It would be technically in line with what it's doing and removes the undocumented reliance on the previous check.  It also has no effect on actual performance, just readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 11):

> In a .NET program that's written to follow declarative style, what are some legitimate uses for ReferenceEquals()?

There is only one legitimate use of ReferenceEquals regardless of the "style" in which the program is written: *to compare two references for reference equality*.

If you are using ReferenceEquals for something other than comparing two references for reference equality, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Err, I think OP is asking the use cases for comparing references for reference equality. Beyond this obvious any insight you can provide will be very helpful.

Comment: A bit tautological for my tastes.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Tautological, sure. But consider the number of people who use GetHashCode for something other than balancing a hash table. Or the number of people who use string *ordering* when they need string *equality*. Or the number of people who use *Count()* when they mean *Any()*.

Comment: @EricLippert I agree with your comments on principle.  But I too found your response a bit tautological.

Comment: @GregC: If you want a more specific answer then ask a more specific question.

Comment: Much better phrasing than mine @CodeInChaos. Eric, I think the question is specific "what is a good place for ReferenceEquals?". The answer, "it is a good place when you need to check if two references are equal" is tautological. Other answers here mention its use in implementing `operator ==` which is a valid use case but it sort of simple and I for one am definitely interested in learning from you where else it may be useful or valid.

Comment: @EricLippert I followed your advice and broke it out into a more specific question.  When I saw your response, I thought back to Liskov's lectures.  Use it when it makes intuitive sense, don't use it when it does not.  For me, I have a big "intuition fail" moment with operator==, operator!=, Equals(), and ReferenceEquals().  These are especially hard to talk about out loud.  As I am pulling up your excellent blog on the issue to learn some more.  Cheers.

Comment: @GregC: You will get no argument from me there. It is totally confusing how many different ways there are to compare two things for equality, and it gets even worse when you throw ordering into the mix.

Comment: @dnkulkarni: The compiler generates a reference comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the design and/or usage of the related objects is such that there is never more than one instance of any object that is "equal" to any other, then it will be correct, and it's likely to be quicker than comparing some number of instance variables.

Or, as posted in another answer, you can check it first as an "easy out" and only perform a deep equals check if they are different.  This usage it just a performance improvement.